# Engine instrument panel with duplicate Charge light, one incandescent and the other LED

Tags: led, charge, alternator, incandescent

I have an engine in a boat. The ignition on switch, start, and heat are on a panel on the navigation desk. There is also a power LED, incandescent charge, and led oil light. All the engine instruments are on another panel elsewhere.I want to duplicate the lights on this panel, LED power and LED oil are easy, I can parallel these but the charge light is giving me thoughts.

How do I connect the LED light with the incandescent charge light, parallel or series. I know the field coils need current through the bulb to start but how will the LED affect this?

I know mechanics don't have a clue but I thought you guys would as I cant be the only one to do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If the charge system uses the traditional circuit with a lamp connected between the ignition and the field rectifier, you may add 1-2 more incandescent in parallel with no ill effects.

You will even get some fail safety, because burnt charge lamp generally makes the alternator hard to start at low rpm.

No matter what the circuit is, a LED in series with 1k-2k resistor can always be added in parallel to a 12v incandescent and no one will notice - the current will be less than the incandescent bulb parameter accuracy.